# How can I disable the mouse click on the button action event?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

Is there a way I can disable mouse click ? In the panel there are different components and for some of the Button Click events, I want to disable the mouse click. I mean the click of the mouse doesn't have any effect on the components. I can disable using the `setEnabled()` function but I don't want to do that way.

Is there any way I can disable the mouse click ?

Situation :

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
       //..disable the mouse click on each component present inside the panel
}
```

Comment: Does your button has any `ActionListener`? You want the user click on the button and nothing happens or the user cannot click on the button?

Comment: do you want to consume() mouseevents only ???, but whats with events came from KeyBoard (Enter and Tab are implemented as accelerators)

Comment: no, that's definitely not what you should want: a well-behaved user interface must be equally well usable by keyboard _and_ mouse. What's your _real_ goal?

Comment: @Genzer cannot click the button

Comment: @mKorbel there is no scope for that _(accelerators)_ . After the user clicks a button, he should not be able to click on anything.All other buttons be disabled

Comment: this info dramatically changed your request, please edit your question with all ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extended ActionListener to all the buttons like this:

```
public abstract class ExtendedActionListener implements ActionListener{

    private static boolean disabled = false;

    public static void setDisabled(boolean disabled){
        ExtendedActionListener.disabled  = disabled;
    }

    @Override
    public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(disabled)
            return;

        doSomething;

    }
}
```

And now just disable all the ActionListeners by calling the method `setDisabled(false)`. The Button visual behavior doesn't change at all, but nothing happens, when you click on it.

If the visual click behaviour doesn't matter, then you can just remove the MouseListeners.

Comment: there's already a type of ActionListener with a enabled property: it's called Action :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a button group like this:

```
public class SingleSelectionButtonGroup {

    private final List<JButton> buttons;

    public static SingleSelectionButtonGroup group(List<JButton> buttons) {
        return new SingleSelectionButtonGroup(buttons);
    }

    public static SingleSelectionButtonGroup group(JButton...buttons) {
        return new SingleSelectionButtonGroup(Arrays.asList(buttons));
    }

    private SingleSelectionButtonGroup(List<JButton> buttons) {
        this.buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>(buttons);
        setupListener();
    }

    private void setupListener() {
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SingleSelectionButtonGroup.this.disableAllExcept((JButton) e.getSource());
            }
        };

        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            button.addActionListener(listener);
        }
    }

    private void disableAllExcept(JButton clickedButton) {
        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            if (!clickedButton.equals(button)) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And then uses it with a collection of buttons that you want to group:

```
public class Application {

    public void run() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        final JPanel pane = new JPanel();

        List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        String[] texts = {"A", "B", "C"};

        for (String text : texts) {
            JButton button = new JButton(text);
            buttons.add(button);
            pane.add(button);
        }

        SingleSelectionButtonGroup.group(buttons);      
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you should use one common class of your listener and have static method for turn listener turn on and off**

```
public abstract class BaseMouseListener implements ActionListener{

private static boolean active = true;
public static void setActive(boolean active){
    BaseMouseListener.active = active;
}

protected abstract void doPerformAction(ActionEvent e);

@Override
public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(active){
        doPerformAction(e);
    }
}
}
```

**your listeners would have to implements** `doPerformedAction()`

Answer (score -2):

Add empty mouse listener. This will "disable" the click because it will not have any effect.

Comment: Won't the button still receive the action event? I understand that he wants an `ActionListener`, but that do not listen to an action triggered by mouse.

Comment: I didn't understand you.Let us suppose there are 6 buttons and I press one of them. As I press it, I want to disable the mouse click on each of the buttons present there. How will adding an empty mouse listener help in that ? Even if I keep the mouse listener empty,I can still press the other buttons

Comment: hmm ... and why would you add that empty listener, to start with?

Comment: @kleopatra because that's what the answer says.

Comment: @TomášZato the answer is plain wrong - adding an empty listener of whatevertype has exactly no effect on listeners that are already registered - so I wanted to know how/why it might work ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra I thought you're talking to saplingPro, not AlexR. Because yes, the answer is wrong, but I wouldn't call anybody out for trying it, just to be sure. I did try it too actually before downvoting this answer.